# How to determine if the process waits input from the user

Tags: java, processbuilder

My app is to take c++ CPP file and compile it and then run it. everything seems to be perfect. but when the user forgets to but the input and the c++ program require an input the program stops working. so is there is a way to know if the c++ program requires user input or not so I can handle the situation when the user forgets to but input? and if not how can I treat this situation?

my code for run function is:

```
public void runFile(String input) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "./a.out");
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        writer.write((input + "\n").getBytes());
        writer.flush();

        String s = null;
        // Read the output from the command:
        textArea2.setText(stdInput.readLine());
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            textArea2.setText(textArea2.getText() + "\n" + s);
        
        // Read any errors from the attempted command:
        if((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            textArea2.setText(s);
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                textArea2.setText(textArea2.getText() + "\n" + s);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        textArea2.setText(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, don't write `input` unless it is non-empty, and close the `writer` after writing it.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne  The same bug happen when  the c++ program require two inputs for example and the user enter only one input ! how to handel that ?

Comment: Keep taking input from the user and feeding it to the process?

Comment: What happen is that my java app stop working and freezing  and the only way to stop it the tasks manger ! i tried to make what you said before but i didnt find any way to  do that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searches and reading about this bug I found that there is no way to know if the process waits for input before writing output and also there is no way in `Process` [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to stop the java program from being frozen and stopped working when the c++ program requires two inputs for example and the user entered only one input.

**How to deal with this situation:** I used `Thread` as shown in the new code below to keep the java program alive when this situation acquires and stops it from being frozen.

```
public byte runFile(String input, byte compilere, String fileName) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

        if (compilere == 0) // c++  code
            processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "./a.out");
        else
            processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "java " + fileName);

        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        if (!input.isEmpty()) {
            writer.write((input + "\n").getBytes());
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            textArea2.setText("Input field is empty!");
            return 1;
        }

        // Read the output from the command:
        thread1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String s = null;
                    s = stdInput.readLine();
                    if (s != null) {
                        textArea2.setText(s);
                        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
                            textArea2.setText(textArea2.getText() + "\n" + s);
                    }
                    thread2.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        // Read any errors from the attempted command:
        thread2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String s = null;
                    s = stdError.readLine();
                    if (s != null) {
                        textArea2.setText(s);
                        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
                            textArea2.setText(textArea2.getText() + "\n" + s);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread1.start();

        thread3 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(8000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (textArea2.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    textArea2.setText("The input is not complete or the your program is slow !");
                }
            }
        };
        thread3.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        textArea2.setText(textArea2.getText() + "\n" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** After *Marquis of Lorne* 's comment I handled the situation when there is no input and the c++ app requires an input.